# How can I show dividers in an empty RecyclerView like in Microsoft To Do?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add gray dividers to an empty recyclerView, but ItemDecorations only seem to work between actual elements. How can I achieve this effect?

I've thought about creating ghost viewHolders (with only a divider visible), and deleting them as the user fills the recyclerView, but this seems very hacky..

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (Microsoft To Do):
[Dividers in an empty recyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLr2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your recycler View:

```
DividerItemDecoration itemDecor = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext, HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecor);
```

Comment: Sir, User want https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLr2.jpg . Like iOS.

Comment: Hello, this will give that horizontal ruler that OP wants :)

Comment: Like Amiya said, this only gives horizontals lines to items already in the list. I'm looking for horizontal lines in an *empty* recyclerview

Comment: You can populate your viewHolders with empty values or your can keep static views in your layout which will get switched as soon as recyclerView populates.